# Form Fields Not Outputting Alphabetically in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a form with sequentially named fields (field1, field2, etc) that I need to output in the same order for computation purposes. JSTL doesn't seem to sort in alphabetic order by default. Is there a way to do so?

Here is the code:

```
<c:if test="${param.submitted}">

        <c:set var="hits" value="1" />
        <c:set var="damage" value="0" />

        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Attack</th>
                <th>Damage (Orig)</th>
                <th>Damage (Scaled)</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>

        <!-- Loop through form fields -->
        <c:forEach var="information" items="${paramValues}" varStatus="field">
            <!-- Loop through fields' values -->
            <tr>

            <c:forEach var="currentField" items="${information.value}">
                <c:if test="${!empty currentField}">
                    <c:if test="${fn:contains(currentField, '|')}">
                        <c:set var="currentAttack" value="${fn:substringAfter(currentField, '|')}" />
                        <td><c:out value="${hits}" />: <c:out value="${fn:substringBefore(currentField, '|')}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${fn:substringAfter(currentField, '|')}" /></td>

                        <td>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${hits < 3}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + currentAttack}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${hits == 3}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.8}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.8)}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${hits == 4}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.7}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.7)}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${hits == 5}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.6}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.6)}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${hits == 6}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.5}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.5)}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${hits == 7}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.4}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.4)}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${hits == 8}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.3}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.3)}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="${hits == 9}">
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.2}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.2)}" />
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <c:out value="${currentAttack * 0.1}" />
                                <c:set var="damage" value="${damage + (currentAttack * 0.1)}" />
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                        </td>
                        <td><c:out value="${damage}" /></td>

                        <c:set var="hits" value="${hits + 1}" />
                    </c:if>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

        </table>
    </c:if>

    <form action="foo.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
        <c:forEach var="rows" begin="1" end="5" varStatus="stat">
            <p> ${stat.count}:
                <select name="move${stat.count}">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                    <option value="${row.attack}|${row.damage}">${row.attack}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select></p>

        </c:forEach>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSTL doesn't change the sort order or something and has also no facilities at all to sort collections. It just allows you to control the flow of HTML generation in JSP and thus displays whatever *you* told it to display.

Your problem is caused elsewhere. Most likely you're using a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to hold the fields. A `HashMap` is by nature unordered while a `LinkedHashMap` is ordered by insertion order exactly like as a `List`.

---

**Update** you're iterating over the implicit EL variable `${paramValues}` which refers the [`ServletRequest#getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) which indeed returns an unordered `HashMap`. If you need to retain the order of the request parameters, you'd have to solve the problem differently. For example, by using fixed and indexed parameter names so that you can refer them directly, or by just using a MVC framework.

Comment: I'm using <c:forEach> and looping through the form elements. No JSP tags being used explicitly for form output.

Comment: Yes I already understood that. Note that `<c:forEach>` is actually a JSP tag, part of the JSP standard tag library (abbreviated JSTL). Now, did my answer help in solving the problem? Was you indeed using a `HashMap` to hold the items while incorrectly expecting that it holds the items in insertion order?

Comment: Sorry.  Not using a HashMap, and honestly, am not versed enough to.

Comment: JSP just displays whatever you told it to display. It doesn't change the data provided to it. The problem is definitely in the way how you prepared the data before passing the control to JSP. As long as you don't tell anything about it, it's hard to point out the real cause. Best would be to include an SSCCE in your question. Using a `HashMap` instead of `LinkedHashMap` is just the most possible cause for which the described problem symptoms match.

Comment: As per your edit, the implicit EL variable `${paramValues}` is definitely a `HashMap`. So this only confirms my answer more.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm still very new to the Java world and I had no idea of this correlation.